# How to conditional bootstrap angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-bootstrapping

I am trying to bootstrap my angular 5 app based on conditions. Basically I have two modules `MobileModule` and `WebModule` which contains UI components of web and mobile separately.

I am trying to bootstrap `MobileModule` if user has opened the app in mobile browser otherwise `WebModule`.

Here is my `main.ts` source.

```
import { enableProdMode }         from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { environment }    from './environments/environment';

import { AppSettings }    from './app/core/app-settings';
import { MobileModule }   from './app/mobile/mobile.module';
import { WebModule }      from './app/web/web.module';


if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}


/*
 * Bootstrap mobile or web module based on mobile
 * or desktop client.
 */
if (AppSettings.isMobileDevice) {

  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MobileModule)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
} else {

  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(WebModule)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

`web.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
import { CoreModule }       from '../core/core.module';
import { SharedModule }     from '../shared/shared.module';
import { AuthModule }       from './auth/auth.module';

import { SignupComponent }  from './auth/signup/signup.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,        // Support for common angular directives and services
    AppRoutingModule,     // Web routing controller module.
    CoreModule,           // Core modules
    SharedModule,         // Shared modules
    AuthModule,           // App authentication module (signup and login)
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [SignupComponent]    // Bootstrap Signup component
})
export class WebModule { }
```

`mobile.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
import { CoreModule }       from '../core/core.module';
import { SharedModule }     from '../shared/shared.module';
import { AuthModule }       from './auth/auth.module';

import { SignupComponent }  from './auth/signup/signup.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,        // Support for common angular directives and services
    AppRoutingModule,     // Mobile app routing controller module
    CoreModule,           // Core modules
    SharedModule,         // Shared modules
    AuthModule,           // App authentication module (signup and login)
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [SignupComponent]    // Bootstrap Signup component
})
export class MobileModule { }
```

The above approach is working fine with `ng serve` but when I try to run it using `ng serve --aot` option its throwing error in chrome console.

```
Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'WebModule'.  
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (compiler.js:20242)  
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15195)  
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34405)  
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)  
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34260)  
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)  
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5567)  
    at eval (main.ts:26)  
    at Object../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:53)  
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
```

My project structure is

```
|-node_modules
|-src
   |-app
      |-core
      |-mobile
         |-mobile.module.ts
      |-shared
      |-web
         |-web.module.ts
```

I tried several things to conditionally bootstrap the app but no success. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add both module files also

Comment: @AnasBinNazeer I have updated with both module sources.

Comment: Can you try to upgrade typescript & angular-cli version ?

Comment: Tried but no success. Typescript version `^2.6.2` and angular cli `1.7.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot research I found that we can only bootstrap single module at a time. Which means single root module per angular app.

However, since the time of [angular lazy loading of modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) we can load all feature modules dynamically. Hence, the idea is to load one root module and based on conditions you can load any sub-module dynamically.

Let's consider above example.

```
import { enableProdMode }         from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { environment }    from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule }      from './app/app.module';


if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}


/*
 * Bootstrap single root module
 */
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes }     from '@angular/router';

import { CoreModule }       from '../core/core.module';
import { SharedModule }     from '../shared/shared.module';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';


const isMobileDevice = true; // Mobile device condition    


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path        : 'app',
    loadChildren: isMobileDevice ? './mobile/mobile.module#MobileModule' : './web/web.module#WebModule'    // Conditionally load mobile or web module
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,        // Support for common angular directives and services
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    CoreModule,           // Core modules
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]    // Bootstrap Signup component
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Hope this helps to some other folks who wanted such behaviour in their angular app.

Answer (score 2):

I think Angular 5 does not support multiple root modules, because the way AOT (Ahead of Time compilation) currently works. It seems it only compiles the first module and its dependencies.

A workaround is to have a root module only for bootstrapping, and use Router with Guards, and lazy-loading only the desired module inside the root module.

References:

- Related Issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4624
- Lazy-Loading Modules: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the conditionally loading of a module in `main.ts` by using `fileReplacements` in the angular.json file by creating an object under configuration and in that, I added replacements as below:

```
"fileReplacements": [
    {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.lib.ts"
    },
    {
        "replace": "src/main.ts",
        "with": "src/main.lib.ts"
    }
]
```

The above solved my problem.

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks...